# Retrieved data from XML showing as Object object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have the follow XML structure:

```
<item>
  <title>title</title>
  <description>description</description>
</item>
```

And the following approach to get and display the XML"

```js
$.ajax({
  url:'feed.xml',
  dataType:'xml',
  type:'GET', 
  success: xmlParser,
});

function xmlParser(xml){
  $(xml).find("item").each(function(){
    $("#container").append('<div class="test">' + $(this).find("title") + '</div>');   
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- print results here -->
</div>
```

But, on the page, it prints `[Object object]` six times (because there's six `item's`). Unsure why?

Comment: Did you try to see how it looks if you use JSON.stringify? `JSON.stringify($(this).find("title"), null, 4)`

Comment: That is default result of `toString` method that is called on object when you have object to string coercion.

Comment: `$(this).find("title")` returns a jQuery object. Use [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function) properly, and read ex. `text` of the tag.

Comment: try `console.log(xml);` to see detail, for design your output.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find("title")` returns a jQuery object. I am assuming you want the text inside to be displayed. You can do that with the jQuery [text method](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

```js
function xmlParser(xml) {
  $(xml).find("item").each(function() {
    $container.append('<div class="test">' + $(this).find("title").text() + '</div>');
  });
};

var $container = $("#container");
var xml = "<items><item><title>title 1</title><description>description 1</description></item><item><title>title 2</title><description>description 2</description></item><item><title>title 3</title><description>description 3</description></item></items>";

xmlParser(xml);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- print results here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `+` operator implicitly calls `toString` on `$(this).find("title")`. The simplest way to fix this is to use the comma operator.

```js
function xmlParser(xml) {
  $(xml).find("item").each(function() {
    $("#container").append('<div class="test">' + $(this).find("title").text() + '</div>');
  });
};

var data = "<item><title>title</title><description>description</description></item>";

xmlParser(xml);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```